# Configuration vs Operational within NETCONF/YANG

Tags: netconf

NETCONF/YANG touts being able to provide a clear split between distinguishing the configuration from operational state. 
However Im unable to see the clear way this is done.

I can see some RFCs stating NETCONF (the protocol) does (or could) this datastores.
But I also see reference to the YANG schemas stating that this is done via a split in the model. Based on making one of the containers RO and just naming it so (i.e interface-state). Or via  , .

Anyone able to clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the IETF models are being created (e.g.: RFC8022 - A YANG Data Model for Routing Management) there are separate trees for both the configuration and the operational state.

The operational state containers are then defined as Read-Only through the use of the:

```
config "false";
```

tag inside each one.

Comment: Thanks - Does this mean the information resides within a different datastore within NETCONF? As NETCONF states only configuration datastores. And only RESTCONF seems to split the datastores into conf and operational.